# How to replace a key value string with specific string in fluentd

Tags: replace, fluentd

I am new to the fluentd, I want to use record_modifier to replace the string, when specific string occurs in the key value.

Example

1)input :

```
{"message":"how are you"}
```

output :

```
{"message":"who are you"}
```

when input key value having "how", i want to replace that string with "who"

2)input :

```
{"message":"he is a bad boy"}
```

output :

```
{"message":"he is a good boy"}
```

when input key value having "bad", i want to replace that string with "good"

> @type record_modifier
>    #auto_typecast true
>   `enter code here`
>   key message
>    expression ?????
>    replace ?????

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Your posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example <https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve>. For more information, please see How to Ask<https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask> and take the tour<stackoverflow.com/tour>.

Comment: I am using to below code for solving the above issue but it is not working <filter **>
@type record_modifier
  #auto_typecast true
<replace>
  key message
expression ^.*\b(bad)\b.*
#  replace "good"
</replace>
</filter>

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: I think this will work here - https://github.com/repeatedly/fluent-plugin-record-modifier

Answer (score 0):

you can use ***gsub*** in a ***record_transformer***

```
<filter yourTag>
  @type record_transformer
  enable_ruby
  <record>
    log ${record["log"].gsub('how', 'who')}   
  </record>
</filter>
```